# Exception when trying to sort linq query by a nested aggregated value

Tags: c#, sorting, linq-to-sql

Have a weird issue when trying to sort linq results by an aggregated value from multiple nested field. Same issue happens for any aggregate method (average, sum, min).
Tried different approaches to prevent the exception, but getting either null reference or sequence contains no items (invalid operation).

Here is what I'm trying to do - get TopLevelItem array including two nested arrays and sort it by an aggregated value in the second level array.
Some of the Items/Subitems lists can be empty.

Here is a code example that throws null reference exception (can't figure out where exactly it occurs as linq doesn't give me much hint).

```
IQueryable<TopLevelItem> query = repository.TopLevelItems
                .Include(x => x.Items)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Subitems);

var ordeByClause = x => x.Items.Sum(y => y.Subitems.Sum(z => z.NullableDecimalParameter ?? 0));

query = query.OrderBy(orderByClause);

var results = query.ToList();
```

Also tried to use select, but with the same result:

```
var ordeByClause = x => x.Items.SelectMany(y => y.Subitems.Select(z => z.NullableDecimalParameter ?? 0).DefaultIfEmpty(0)).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
```

Any idea what am I missing/doing wrong?

---

Edit

I have done some further investigation and it seems the problem is when the *x.Items* array is null (do not exist any Items for a given TopLevelItem). Linq generates the following sql for every row from the results (what is not very efficient):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT SUM(COALESCE([y.SubItems].[NullableDecimalParameter], 0.0))
FROM [Items] AS [y0]
INNER JOIN [SubItems] AS [y.SubItems] ON [y0].[Id] = [y.SubItems].[ItemId]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [y0].[TopLevelItemId]',N'@_outer_Id uniqueidentifier',@_outer_Id='some_guid'
```

As the Items array is null, the whole query returns null and linq fails on an exception. Using DefaultIfEmpty seems to only change the **INNER JOIN** for **LEFT JOIN** but with the same result.

Not sure if this is a bug in Linq or something per design, but I could not figure out a way to work it around.

Comment: Where do you have exception?

Comment: When performing the `query.ToList()`

Comment: So query is null? Are you sure he should not be? What are repository and the type definition? Have you some data in it that match the query?

Comment: Query is not null, data are fine, it is only the sorting part that makes troubles for some reason. Some of the sub-level arrays (Items/Subitems) are empty what I believe should fix the second case with `DefaultIfEmpty(0)`, but still getting the null exception in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Linq delays the evaluation query until the value is iterated.

This means that the query (`Include`, `ThenInclude`, `Sum`, `OrderBy`) will not be executed until the code reaches `query.ToList()`

If you want to know where the exception occurs, split the query and evaluate it with a `.ToList()`

Comment: Problem is in evaluation of the orderby part, sorting by sum on first level property works fine, problem is with the nesting. I don't see many options to split the query in a way that would help debugging. I've checked the data acquired by the query before sorting and seemed all fine.